# Parse a Text File with Multiple Line Comments

Tags: c#, fileparsing

I have a file with the following format

> ```
> -----------------------------------
> File: test.cs
> Some Text Here 
> http:\\link
>
>    Comment #1
>
>    Comment #2
>
>    Comment #X
>
> -----------------------------------
> ```

I have the following class:

```
public class TextFile
{
    public string File;
    public string Description;
    public string Link;
    public List<string> Comments;
}
```

So far, I am able to grab all the text between the "-" lines, and have them stored in a local string buffer. Now, I am trying to parse that string buffer into the TextFile class. The issue I have is that the Comments can contain new line characters, so I can't simply split the buffer, and then parse the string array.

Comment: It's a bit difficult; if a comment can contain newline characters, how would you know where the comments ends; is there a certain terminal symbol? Or is every line belonging to the comment indented by 3 characters, as shown in the example?

Comment: Don't split lines, split keywords ("Comment")  ==> then the newline characters aren't a problem anymore

Comment: @Codor yes it does look like each comment is indented by 2 characters.

Comment: So a comment can't contain the phrase "  Comment #N" and never will?

Comment: The comments actually don't start with "Comment", I just put that in there for simplicity sake.

Comment: Yeah so you need to define a pattern and implement that. Start by showing the actual pattern in your question. If each new comment is prepended by two spaces, the same question remains: a comment can't _contain_ a newline followed by two spaces (even though you show three)?

Comment: How are you delineating between comments?  You need someway to know when a new comment begins.

Comment: It's exactly like CodeCaster mentioned, you have to set a exact pattern for your informations and read like you have set your pattern, that's the only way to handly things like this

Comment: This is a file that gets exported, so I don't have much control over the format of it. My snippet shows 3 spaces because I manually entered that information. But I can control how the comments are formatted, so I can prevent users from entering a comment followed by a new line and 2 spaces.